# Passing constructor with parameters to another constructor as argument

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have a struct Point, which has a constructor with parameters and a class called Circle.

```
struct Point{
    int x, y;
    Point(){}
    Point(int ox, int oy) : x(ox),y(oy){}
};

class Circle{
    public:
    Point obj;
    int radius;
    Circle(Point pt(int ox, int oy), int raza) : obj.x(ox), obj.y(oy), radius(raza) {}
};

int main()
{
    Circle(Point p(2,3),3);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass  a struct constructor with parameters as parameter to my Circle class constructor.

Comment: Do you want `Circle` to accept `Point` as its parameter, or do you want `Circle` to accept parameters used to create a `Point`? In other words, do you want `Circle` to create a `Point` from two ints or do you want the outside world to create `Point` and you (in `Circle`) will not care about how it was created?

Comment: I wanna use x and y from point as cardinal coordinates for the center of the circle. I wanna test if two circles intersect each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this :

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(int x, int y) :
        m_x(x),
        m_y(y)
    {
    }

private:
    int m_x{ 0 };
    int m_y{ 0 };
};

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(const Point& pt, int raza) :
        m_point{ pt },
        m_radius{ raza }
    {
    }


private:
    Point m_point;
    int m_radius;

};

int main()
{
    Circle c1(Point(2,3), 3);

    // or use this shorter variant.
    // first parameter is a Point, {2,3} looks for a constructor 
    // of Point with two ints of point and finds it.
    Circle c2({ 2,3 }, 3);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare variables with m_name? It is some kind of convention?

Comment: There are several conventions for naming members, I use this one. Other's postfix members with an '_'.  But it makes it easy in code to distinguish between member variables and local variables. The goal is to improve readability. (Oh and you can use x as parameter to constructor to initialize m_x without running into naming conflicts)

Comment: So it stays for member, nice, thank you! Everyday learn new things.

Comment: Yes it is short for member_

Answer (score 2):

```
Circle(Point pt(int ox, int oy), int raza) : obj.x(ox), obj.y(oy), radius(raza) {}
```

is wrong syntax and should simply be:

```
Circle(Point pt, int raza) : obj(pt), radius(raza) {}
```

And then

```
Circle circle(Point(2, 3), 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you intended could be done in the following ways

```
Circle(int ox, int oy, int raza) : 
    obj(ox, oy)
    radius(raza) 
    {}
```

Or

```
Circle(Point const& pt, int raza) :
    obj(pt), //note, here is the implicitly defined copy-constructor of obj called, not the one you defined
    radius(raza)
    {}
```

So If you define either of the constructors above the following will be valid

```
Circle        crl(1,2,3); //valid for the first constructor
Circle crl(Point(1,2),3); //valid for the second constructor
Circle    crl({1, 2}, 3); //valid for the second constructor
```